# Update the state of one reducer based on state of another reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've got an state in a reducer with a state that looks like this:

This state handles the current user selections.

```
const selection = {
  timespan: "-3660",
  customTimespan: false,
  pathIds: [''],
  source: undefined,
  direction: 0,
  appClassIds: []
};
```

And I have another state in another reducer that has a list of items appClasses that the user can toggle on or off on a tree.

The state is appClasses.

The thing is that when the user selects something I update appClasses state but also I have to update selection.appClassIds depending on the new state of appClasses.

My question is how can I update a state of a reducer based on the state of another reducer? Or do I have to combine the states in one state?

Something like:

```
const initialState = {
appClasses = [],
selection: {
  timespan: "-3660",
  customTimespan: false,
  pathIds: [''],
  source: undefined,
  direction: 0,
  appClassIds: []
 }
};
```

Comment: To confirm - reducers are inherently stateless - like...they are pure functions by definition and don't maintain any state.  Are you asking: "How do I handle cross cutting concerns in my redux application?"

Comment: Well yes, as I say I have two reducers one depends on the state of the other.

Comment: Please see the Redux FAQ entry on the topic, at http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Reducers.html#reducers-share-state .

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
function a(state, action) { }
function b(state, action, a) { } // depends on a's state

function something(state = {}, action) {
  let a = a(state.a, action);
  let b = b(state.b, action, a); // note: b depends on a for computation
  return { a, b };
}
```

Cheers:)