# Complex state modifications on a reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm sending from the view to an action this.props.appClasses This is the view:

```
 <div key={key} className='SDWanAppClassTreeItem' onClick={this.props.actions.handleToggleAppClass.bind(this,this.props.appClasses, 0, key)}>
```

In the action I modify appClasses that I get from the view, I want to send appClasses modified to the reducer to update the appClasses state. But it gives me an error before reach the reducer.

> A state mutation was detected

This is the action:

```
export function handleToggleAppClass(appClasses, parentAppClassId, appClassId) {
  // console.log('handleToggleAppClass', appClassId, this.appClasses[appClassId]);

  if (appClass.parentAppClassId == 0) {
    // Flip the appClass Show Property
    appClasses[appClass.appClassId].show = appClasses[appClass.appClassId].show ? false : true;

    if (Object.keys(appClasses[appClass.appClassId].children).length !== 0) {
      // Regardless if we enable or disabled the parent, all children should be disabled
      for (var childKey in appClasses[appClass.appClassId].children) {
        appClasses[appClass.appClassId].children[childKey].show = false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    // If we are enabling a child, make sure parent is disabled
    if (!appClasses[appClass.parentAppClassId].children[appClass.appClassId].show) {
      appClasses[appClass.parentAppClassId].show = false;
    }
    appClasses[appClass.parentAppClassId].children[appClass.appClassId].show = appClasses[appClass.parentAppClassId].children[appClass.appClassId].show ? false : true;
  }

  dispatch(handleUpdateInitialSourceFetch(appClasses));

  return { type: types.TOGGLE_APP_CLASS, appClasses };
}
```

I already have appClasses in the state, what I wanted was to send the modified appClasses and update the state in the reducer. I want to to it this way because I read that reducers should be simple, and the modification as you can see in the action are complex. Can I do this kind of complex modifications in the reducer? Because here is giving me an error because I'm sending this.props.appClasses. If I do this on the reducer I don't have to send appClasses because is on the state of the reducer.

So in one line, can I make this complex modifications on a reducer instead of make them on the action?

Comment: Same answer as before--you can't modify the state directly.  You still need to use a cloning/slicing/whatever mechanism whether you're passing in the already-altered state or you're altering it in the reducer.

Comment: If I change it on the reducer I don't have to send appClasses because I have that on the state. I only will be sending parentAppClassId, appClassId, and with that modify the state. My question is: It is a good practice to put all that code on the reducer?

Comment: Yes--that's what reducers are for, altering the state given a set of parameters. Action creators are just that--for creating actions. Where the functionality actually *lives* is a separate issue; it can be a standalone function (easy to test) that's called from the reducer.

Comment: I was doing that on the action because I need to update the state of another reducer based on the final state of appClasses calling dispatch(handleUpdateInitialSourceFetch(appClasses)); I need to find a way to update one state based on another reducer state. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880082/update-the-state-of-one-reducer-based-on-state-of-another-reducer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that computes the new appClasses state and dispatch two actions sending this new state inside each action. 
Then you dispatch this function itself using redux-thunk middleware.

It will look like this:

```
function handleSomeUserInteraction(appClasses, parentAppClassId, appClassId) {

  return function(dispatch) {

    //make a copy of appClasses, so you wont change the state directly
    let newAppClasses = Object.assign({}, appClasses)        

    //do all logic work to compute new appClasses
    //...
    //...

    //handleUpdateInitialSourceFetch
    dispatch({ type: types.UPDATE_INITIAL_SOURCE_FETCH, appClasses: newAppClasses }

    //handleToggleAppClass
    dispatch({ type: types.TOGGLE_APP_CLASS, appClasses: newAppClasses })    

  }
}
```

You can learn more about this here:
http://jamesknelson.com/can-i-dispatch-multiple-actions-from-redux-action-creators/